# what is the command to find which interrupt driver is using in the hardware?

Tags: c++, c, interrupt, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I am using Embedded PC (FIT PC2) with QNX RTOS.
I planned to create a handler and taking the timestamp when the interrupt occurs. but I am not successful in that. So someone please help me how to find or the command to know which and where is the intrrupt driver in a hardware ?? so that I will take the timestamp directly from the driver.

Comment: This is your sixth question on the subject of timer interrupts *within the last 24 hours*. Indeed the only questions you have asked on SO so far. Your questions collected one upvote and two downvotes so far, *total*. If your questions do not get answered, asking what is essentially the *same* question *again* isn't the way to go. Think about why your previous questions didn't get answered...

Comment: why wasn't answered ??

Comment: Because it is difficult to tell what you are asking. Your English is lacking, as is your source code. You *started* with very bad Linux code, and tried to force it to work on QNX. You failed to address the problems people pointed out in previous comments. Programming is very much about *precision*, and about taking one step after another...

Answer (score 0):

To find which interrupt driver is running on a given interrupt, use "sin irq"